# Pythonic representation of a list of values with optional flags

Tags: python

What first pops into my head is a dictionary with keys acting as list values and dictionary values defaulting to `None`, but this feels sub-optimal to me. Can anyone propose a single-structure (i.e. no separate 'options' dict) alternative where `dict[key]` on an item with no flags set returns `None` and otherwise returns a list of flags? Apologies if I am overlooking some obvious convention.

A simple use for this structure could be an `order` instance where each item can optionally contain modifications (i.e. no nuts).

Comment: May I encourage you to reconsider one aspect of your design? If you return a list of flags when there are any flags, you should probably return an empty list (rather than `None`) when there are no flags. That simplifies the contract ("... returns a list containing exactly the flags set on the item") and means you can say things like `for flag in dict[key]: ...` without needing an explicit `None` test or exception handler.

Comment: When you say a *list* of values, do you actually mean a list (i.e., there's an order to it, and the same thing can occur multiple times), or a set (i.e., no order, no repetitions), or what? Using a `dict` or `defaultdict` seems like a good solution if it's a set of items you want rather than a list; otherwise, not so good.

Comment: Conversely: do you really want a list of flags, or a set?

Comment: My thinking was that if `None` is returned when the list is empty (same thing *can* occur multiple times, adhering to my previous analogy this would mean two instances of the same item being ordered, potentially with different options), then I can go `if list:` to do stuff on items with options. But, `() == False`, so I have gone with `defaultdict(lambda: ())`. Or is that redundant somehow?

Comment: I think I might be contradicting myself. I don't need an empty list returned because any flag processing will be in an `if list` block anyway. So there is no advantage to returning an empty list known to me aside from consistency and perhaps convention.

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda:())` can be more simply written `defaultdict(tuple)`

Comment: `()` is false (though that doesn't mean `() == False` -- try it) but `[]` is false too, and so is `set()` and so is `{}`. You should probably use `[]` if your flags are in a list, or `set()` if they're in a set, as your default, rather than `()`. (It's often a bad sign when the possible return values from a function are not all of the same type.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a defaultdict will do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

flags = defaultdict(lambda : None)
flags.update({'F1':True,'F3':True,'F8':True})

for f in 'F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8'.split():
    print f, '->', flags[f]
```

Prints:

```
F1 -> True
F2 -> None
F3 -> True
F4 -> None
F5 -> None
F6 -> None
F7 -> None
F8 -> True
```

Comment: Yeah, this is good. Figured I'd have to write a manager of some sort if I rolled my own structure.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities:

1) `dict.get(key, None)` returns `None` if there is no entry for `key`.

2) `dict = defaultdict( lambda: None )` creates a dict that automatically returns `None` if there is no entry for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have gathered from my comments above, I'm not sure exactly what your real requirements are. But my guess is that they're a little different from what's implied by the suggestions of a `defaultdict`. It sounds to me as if you want a *list* of items (ordered, perhaps with repetitions allowed), each associated with a perhaps-empty *set* of flags. In which case, the simplest solution is probably a list of pairs `(item,flags)`, where each `flags` is a set object.

This doesn't give you the ability to look up the flags by the *value* of `item`, but that doesn't sound to me like something you should be doing anyway. (Taking your restaurant-order example, there might be two people whose `item` is, say, `HouseSalad`, but only one of them might have the `no_nuts` flag.)

You can of course get a list of flags from each item's set just by calling `list` on it.

In any specific application, it might well be worth making a class to hold this information and provide more transparent ways of accessing it. That would make it easier to add in extra features if you realise you need them (random example: the ability to find all items with a given flag).

Comment: If one was to go with the list-of-pairs option, you'd have to do `len(key)` to determine whether a given item had flags set. The class approach, although very extensible, sounds a lot like how Django defines database models, although that is a misleading comparison because the entire structure I'm talking about would be sort of like a `ManyToManyField` with optional flags set on each relationship. So this is really only a small part of the picture. Thanks though!

Comment: You wouldn't have to do `len(key)`. Empty sets, like empty lists and tuples, are false.